# Overloading operators in a Rectangle Class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

My program will not run and is giving me error messages. At first, I forgot to place a semicolon after the `}` in the header file.  I went back and added one but Visual Studio keeps giving me errors.

### Link to error messages: https://pastebin.com/wSEnedMY

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H
using namespace std; 

// Class declaration
class Rectangle
{
    private: 
        double length; 
        double width; 
    public: 
        Rectangle(); 
        Rectangle(double, double); 
        Rectangle operator-(Rectangle &);
        Rectangle operator*(Rectangle &);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream &, Rectangle &);
}; 
#endif

#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include "Rectangle.h" 
using namespace std; 

// Default Constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    length = 0; 
    width = 0; 
}

// Constructor 
Rectangle::Rectangle(double len, double wid)
{
    length = len; 
    width = wid; 
}

// Overload the - operator 
Rectangle Rectangle::operator-(Rectangle &otherRect)
{
    Rectangle temp;

    temp.length = this->length - otherRect.length;
    temp.width = this->width - otherRect.width;

    return temp;
}

// Overload the * operator
Rectangle Rectangle::operator*(Rectangle &otherRect)
{
    Rectangle temp;

    temp.length = this->length * otherRect.length;
    temp.width = this->width * otherRect.width;

    return temp;
}

// Overload the cin operator
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Rectangle& r)
{
    // Prompt user for length
    cout << "Enter the length: ";
    is >> r.length;

    // Prompt user for width
    cout << "Enter the width: ";
    is >> r.width;

    return is;
}

#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "Rectangle.h" 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    Rectangle r1(3,5);
    Rectangle r3, r4, r5, r6;
    Rectangle r2(r1);               // Copy constructor

    cin >> r2;                      // Read in value for r2 and to be overloaded
    
    r3 = r1 – r2;
    cout << r3;

    r4 = r1 * r2;
    cout << r4;

    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0;
```

---

> This is student 9*********. Please ignore this message as this is for any of my instructors who come across this post. I have been advised to do this to avoid any type of plagiarism issues.

Comment: "Visual Studios keeps giving me error messages", then please include them in your question.

Comment: What are the errors that you are receiving?

Comment: If you are trying to show the errors in that screenshot, they are not readable.  Please just copy them and edit them into your original question. :)

Comment: The message at the top "pollutes" the most visible part of your question. Please consider moving it to the bottom, or even placing it in the comments.

Comment: `Rectangle.h` should include `<istream>` at least, since you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The first is you didn't declare or define an insertion operator.  You are using it here:

```
cout << r3;
```

and

```
cout << r4;
```

Your second problem seems to be that the line you try to subtract two rectangles on has a character that isn't a minus symbol:

```
r3 = r1 – r2
//      ^This isn't a subtraction, it's a hyphen or something.

r3 = r1 - r2
//      ^See the difference?
```

After adding an insertion operator overload, and fixing that minus symbol, your code compiled.

Comment: Thanks @dwcanillas. How would I define the insertion operator to allow it to work? Originally, I had to create a friend ostream in the public section for the class, but it was removed for the assignment's specifications.

Comment: @Mary that sounds like what you would need to do.  I don't see anything in what you have posted limiting you from creating an insertion operator.  You can't `cout << r3` (or `r4`) without defining one, so you would either need to remove those `cout` calls or define the operator.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add include fstream to your headers also make all the headers at the top and overload the output operator if you haven't.I hope this helps you.